# SalesforceExpiredSession Error using simple_salesforce package in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I am trying to download a report I created on SalesForce using simple_salesforce package in python.

Below is the sample code:

```py
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


sf = Salesforce(username='myusername', 
                password='mypassword',
                security_token='mytoken',
                version='46.0')



report_id = 'myreportid'
sf.restful('analytics/reports/{}'.format(report_id))
```

However, this chunk of code yields the following error:

```
SalesforceExpiredSession: Expired session for https://company_name.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v46.0/analytics/reports/myreporid. Response content: [{'message': 'This session is not valid for use with the REST API', 'errorCode': 'INVALID_SESSION_ID'}]
```

Comment: Does your Profile (or any of permission sets assigned to you) have "API User" checkbox enabled? Does it login ok, can you see successes in Setup -> your user -> login history? Does any other "simple" call work like SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 10

Comment: @eyescream Could not find API User checkbox in my profile (Maybe it is not an option on SalesForce Lighting?). When I checked login history, I can see that I was able to login through simple_salesforce package in python (the login record shows login type as Other Apex API, device is SOAP Partner, and session is active.). I tried to use the simple query you provided, it gives ExpiredSessionError. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(continuing from comments)

My bad, typo. Does your Profile have "API Enabled" checkbox ticked?

[image]

And you said you can see success in login history, active session?

What happens when you try to do same thing manually with [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php). Login, then in top menu Utilities -> REST Explorer should let you run your report.

Maybe simple is creating a SOAP session id which for whatever reason is incompatible with REST API (to be fair I thought they were pretty interchangeable, maybe your company disabled REST API, I heard it's possible to request that from SF support...)

If workbench works - you may have to login in simple different way, creating "connected app" and reading up about https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=5&language=en_US for example